# Scrapy FormRequest sending JSON

Tags: python, json, scrapy

I am trying to create a FormRequest that can send content-type:application/json.

Here is what I try:

```
yield FormRequest("abc.someurl.com", formdata=json.dumps({"referenceId":123,"referenceType":456}), headers={'content-type':'application/json'}, callback=self.parseResult2)
```

If I use `json.dumps()` to process the form data in the formdata=, the error I get is

> "exceptions.ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack"

I can't just use the list as in

```
formdata={"referenceId":123,"referenceType":456}
```

The FormRequest works but is not accepted by the server.

```
import requests
import json
result = requests.post(url, json.dumps({"referenceId":123,"referenceType":456}), headers={'content-type':'application/json'})
```

It works from the python command prompt as in the above.

Any ideas?

-KM

Comment: What is the whole stacktrace (error)?

Answer (score 22):

FormRequest is for simulating an HTML form (e.g. application/x-www-form-urlencoded).  It sounds like you are simply wanting to POST data with your Request.  Since you mention a content type of 'application/json' you probably want to do something like this:

```
request = Request( url, method='POST', 
                   body=json.dumps(my_data), 
                   headers={'Content-Type':'application/json'} )
```

Answer (score 6):

```
from scrapy.http import JsonRequest

class TestSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    def start_requests(self):
        data = {
            'name1': 'value1',
            'name2': 'value2',
        }
        yield JsonRequest(url='http://www.example.com/post/action', data=data)
```

see more: [docs.scrapy.org#jsonrequest](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#jsonrequest)

Comment: but how do you get the response after calling JsonRequest?

Comment: try to use
`return JsonRequest`

Answer (score -1):

You could just use the below snippet for getting response:

> > res =requests.post(url, json=data)
> >     print(res.text)

Comment: Requests is another module, OP is asking solution for Scrapy.