# scrapy json response.body different from json response in website

Tags: python, json, request, scrapy, response

I am quite new to scrapy. But I have made a few spiders.

I am trying to scrapy reviews from this website http://www.reviewed.com/search/products?sort=rating,desc . Through firebug I can see that there is a POST request that sends out a json response with the products.
So far my spider looks like this:

```
import scrapy
import json
from scrapy.conf import settings
from scrapy.http import Request
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from reviews.items import ReviewItem
from reviews import utils

class ReviewedbaseSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "reviewedbase" #spider name to call in terminal
    allowed_domains = ['reviewed.com'] #the domain where the spider is allowed to crawl
    start_urls = ['http://www.reviewed.com/search/products?sort=rating,desc'] #url from which the spider will start crawling

    url_post = 'http://cerebro-production.herokuapp.com/products_production/_search'

    def parse(self, response):
        bodydata = '{"query":{"filtered":{"query":{"function_score":{"query":{"match_all":{}},"functions":[{"filter":{"exists":{"field":"review_publish_on"}},"gauss":{"review_publish_on":{"origin":"now","scale":"700d","decay":0.9}}},{"filter":{"term":{"comparable_name":"car"}},"boost_factor":"1.2"},{"linear":{"rating":{"origin":10,"scale":10,"decay":0.9}}},{"filter":{"term":{"archived":false}},"boost_factor":"1.2"},{"filter":{"term":{"has_rating":true}},"boost_factor":"1.2"},{"filter":{"exists":{"field":"review_publish_on"}},"boost_factor":"1.2"}],"score_mode":"multiply"}},"filter":{"and":[{"match_all":{}},{"not":{"terms":{"website_ids":["cruises","cookware","cutlery","kitchenequipment","lenses"]}}}]}}},"filter":{},"sort":[{"archived":"asc"},{"rating":"desc"}],"size":20,"from":0,"aggs":{"has_rating":{"aggs":{"has_rating":{"terms":{"field":"has_rating","size":0}}},"filter":{"and":[{"match_all":{}}]}},"has_awards":{"aggs":{"has_awards":{"terms":{"field":"has_awards","size":0}}},"filter":{"and":[{"match_all":{}}]}}}}'
        req = Request(url=self.url_post,
                    method="POST",
                    headers={"Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*", "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate", "Accept-Language": "pt-PT,pt;q=0.8,en;q=0.5,en-US;q=0.3", "Cache-Control": " no-cache", "Connection": "keep-alive", "Content-Length":  "1009", "Content-Type": "application/json;charset=utf-8", "Pragma": "no-cache", "Referer": "http://www.reviewed.com/search/products?sort=rating,desc", "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.10; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0"},
                    dont_filter=True,
                    body=json.dumps(bodydata),
                    callback=self.parse_json)
        print "------REQUEST-----------" + str(req)
        yield req

    def parse_json(self, response):
        print "---------------RESPONSE.BODY---------------------" + str(response.body)

        json_data = json.loads(response.body)

        #print "-----------------JSON_DATA----------------------" + str(json_data)

        #print "--------HITS----------" + str(json_data["hits"])


    def parse_review(self, response):
         pass
```

What is really confusing me is that my response.body is not the same response from website, that I see in firebug separator "response". In scrapy spider, there are only 10 hits and in response from website there are 20 hits, and really there are 20 products in the firt page (start_url). What am I doing wrong? Am I passing a wrong Request?

I have tested on RESTclient with headers and the bodydata in body request and there is good, is also giving 20 hits.

With this spider I am having an error:

```
2015-05-22 16:34:58+0100 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 0.24.5 started (bot: reviews)
2015-05-22 16:34:58+0100 [scrapy] INFO: Optional features available: ssl, http11
2015-05-22 16:34:58+0100 [scrapy] INFO: Overridden settings: {'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'reviews.spiders', 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['reviews.spiders'], 'DOWNLOAD_DELAY': 1, 'BOT_NAME': 'reviews'}
2015-05-22 16:34:58+0100 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled extensions: LogStats, TelnetConsole, CloseSpider, WebService, CoreStats, SpiderState
2015-05-22 16:34:58+0100 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares: HttpAuthMiddleware, DownloadTimeoutMiddleware, RotateUserAgentMiddleware, RetryMiddleware, DefaultHeadersMiddleware, MetaRefreshMiddleware, RedirectMiddleware, CookiesMiddleware, ChunkedTransferMiddleware, DownloaderStats
2015-05-22 16:34:58+0100 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares: HttpErrorMiddleware, OffsiteMiddleware, RefererMiddleware, UrlLengthMiddleware, DepthMiddleware
2015-05-22 16:34:58+0100 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled item pipelines: 
2015-05-22 16:34:58+0100 [reviewedbase] INFO: Spider opened
2015-05-22 16:34:58+0100 [reviewedbase] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2015-05-22 16:34:58+0100 [scrapy] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6058
2015-05-22 16:34:58+0100 [scrapy] DEBUG: Web service listening on 127.0.0.1:6115
2015-05-22 16:34:59+0100 [reviewedbase] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.reviewed.com/search/products?sort=rating,desc> (referer: None)
------REQUEST-----------<POST http://cerebro-production.herokuapp.com/products_production/_search>
2015-05-22 16:34:59+0100 [reviewedbase] DEBUG: Retrying <POST http://cerebro-production.herokuapp.com/products_production/_search> (failed 1 times): 400 Bad Request
2015-05-22 16:35:00+0100 [reviewedbase] DEBUG: Retrying <POST http://cerebro-production.herokuapp.com/products_production/_search> (failed 2 times): 400 Bad Request
2015-05-22 16:35:02+0100 [reviewedbase] DEBUG: Gave up retrying <POST http://cerebro-production.herokuapp.com/products_production/_search> (failed 3 times): 400 Bad Request
2015-05-22 16:35:02+0100 [reviewedbase] DEBUG: Crawled (400) <POST http://cerebro-production.herokuapp.com/products_production/_search> (referer: http://www.reviewed.com/search/products?sort=rating,desc)
2015-05-22 16:35:02+0100 [reviewedbase] DEBUG: Ignoring response <400 http://cerebro-production.herokuapp.com/products_production/_search>: HTTP status code is not handled or not allowed
2015-05-22 16:35:02+0100 [reviewedbase] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2015-05-22 16:35:02+0100 [reviewedbase] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
    {'downloader/request_bytes': 5384,
     'downloader/request_count': 4,
     'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 1,
     'downloader/request_method_count/POST': 3,
     'downloader/response_bytes': 52191,
     'downloader/response_count': 4,
     'downloader/response_status_count/200': 1,
     'downloader/response_status_count/400': 3,
     'finish_reason': 'finished',
     'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2015, 5, 22, 15, 35, 2, 371278),
     'log_count/DEBUG': 8,
     'log_count/INFO': 7,
     'request_depth_max': 1,
     'response_received_count': 2,
     'scheduler/dequeued': 4,
     'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 4,
     'scheduler/enqueued': 4,
     'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 4,
     'start_time': datetime.datetime(2015, 5, 22, 15, 34, 58, 880902)}
2015-05-22 16:35:02+0100 [reviewedbase] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

400 is a bad request, right? :/ What can I do/change?

Thanks so much for your time and help.

Comment: Have you tried using the form request object instead of creating requests? http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#formrequest-objects

Comment: What user-agent is your scrapy spider sending out?  Have you tried from a different IP?

Comment: Yes I have tried a formrequest before but I saw here in SO http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11236632/scrapy-formrequest-sending-json this... and get back to normal request... @Raiyan

Comment: in request, in headers i have passed "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.10; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0", should I remove it? since my spider is using an rotate_useragent.py by settings @Travis Leleu

Comment: Try removing the Content-Length header, I've had that help when trying to debug a Request with body/cookies.