# Crawling: Difference between "query string parameter" and "request payload"

Tags: json, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to crawl a ajax site using Scrapy, the url is http://www.target.com/p/bounty-select-a-size-white-paper-towels-12-mega-rolls/-/A-14920157#prodSlot=medium_1_2&term=bounty

My goal is to get the store id. I did that by checking all the XHR request in chrome developer tool and find the one with name ("v1?request_type=availability&key=.....") to be the one I want.

My questions are:

1. In developer tool, there is "Query string parameter" which seems to be the part after `?` of the request url.   There is also Request Payload section, which is a json.
   So which one should I use to send to the server? If i need request payload, how can I send a json file?
2. when i send the whole url to get json:
   https://api.target.com/available_to_promise_aggregator/v1?request_type=availability&key=q0jGNkIyuqUTYIlzZKoCfK6ugaNGSP8h

I get "Request method 'GET' not supported", so should I use POST instead or there is something wrong I did?

Comment: Yes. The query string is the part after the `?`. This can contain a number of parameters divided by `&`. The payload is the http request body, but you should not include a body in GET requests. It only makes sense to send json with POST, PUT or PATCH.

Comment: Question 2: This is up to the api you are communicating with. Usually there will be some documentation telling you which methods are permitted for the various end points. It might very well be possible to use POST on an endpoint that doesn't accept GET. If the API is any good, you should be able to get specific details on which methods and data is accepted by using the http OPTIONS method.

Comment: In the case of target.com, the docs can be found here. https://dev.target.com/  They don't seem to offer a public api, which means that web scraping might not be feasible.

Answer (score 1):

You must send the query string as part of the URL after a `?`, as you guessed.

To include a JSON payload in a request, and send the request as a POST request, [use the `method` and `body` parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11423992/939364) of the [`Request`](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.Request) class.