# Passing non str formdata to FormRequest

Tags: python, scrapy

I have a POST request that I need to make to get the products I am trying to scrape, the request formdata is kind of complex, and Scrapy can't accept it the way it is, how can I fix this?

[Formdata](http://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=028ce926f1304346232b0744459a303f):

```
{
  "requests": [
    {
      "indexName": "egypt_products",
      "params": "query=&hitsPerPage=24&maxValuesPerFacet=20&page=1&attributesToRetrieve=permalink%2Cpermalink_ar%2Cpost_title%2Cpost_title_ar%2Cdiscount%2Cdiscount_val%2Cimages%2Cprice%2Cpromotion_offer_json%2Cregular_price%2Csale_price%2Cin_stock&attributesToHighlight=post_title%2Cpost_title_ar&getRankingInfo=1&facetFilters=%5B%5B%22taxonomies.taxonomies_hierarchical.product_cat.lvl0%3AMobiles%20%26%20Tablets%22%5D%5D&facets=%5B%22taxonomies_ar.attr.Brand%22%2C%22taxonomies_ar.attr.Processor%22%2C%22taxonomies_ar.attr.Screen%20Size%22%2C%22taxonomies_ar.attr.Internal%20Memory%22%2C%22taxonomies_ar.attr.Storage%20Size%22%2C%22taxonomies_ar.attr.RAM%22%2C%22taxonomies_ar.attr.Graphics%20Card%22%2C%22taxonomies_ar.attr.Color%22%2C%22taxonomies_ar.attr.OS%22%2C%22taxonomies_ar.attr.Megapixel%22%2C%22price%22%2C%22taxonomies_ar.product_cat%22%2C%22taxonomies.taxonomies_hierarchical.product_cat.lvl0%22%2C%22taxonomies.taxonomies_hierarchical.product_cat.lvl1%22%5D&tagFilters="
    },
    {
      "indexName": "egypt_products",
      "params": "query=&hitsPerPage=1&maxValuesPerFacet=20&page=0&attributesToRetrieve=%5B%5D&attributesToHighlight=%5B%5D&getRankingInfo=1&facetFilters=%5B%5B%22taxonomies.taxonomies_hierarchical.product_cat.lvl0%3AMobiles%20%26%20Tablets%22%5D%5D&attributesToSnippet=%5B%5D&tagFilters=&facets=%5B%22taxonomies.taxonomies_hierarchical.product_cat.lvl0%22%5D"
    }
  ]
}
```

Code:

```
ajax_request = FormRequest(url=self.products_ajax_api,
                           formdata=request_payload,
                           meta={'category_name': category},
                           dont_filter=True,
                           callback=self.post_ajax_request_category)
```

where `request_payload` is the JSON data.
The problem is `formdata` accepts dictionaries in the following format `{'str': 'str'}`, but doesn't accept nested dictionaries as in my case.

Comment: please include you "complex" formdata in your question and tell us what you have done so far!

Comment: @Unlockedluca updated.

Comment: I think this is duplucate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11236632/scrapy-formrequest-sending-json

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scrapy FormRequest sending JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11236632/scrapy-formrequest-sending-json)

Comment: @Granitosaurus no it's different, I know how to send the json formdata, the problem is in it's shape (nested dicts).

Comment: What's wrong with nested dicts? You take python dictionary, convert it to a string with json.dumps and send that string as your POST request body. That's what related question describes.